# WCF authorization with PrincipalPermission always throws System.Security.SecurityException: Request for principal permission failed

Tags: c#, wcf, authorization

I have a WCF service running inside a Windows service (not IIS) and is working fine. It is using NetTcpBinding with the following settings:

```
binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.Windows;
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = TcpClientCredentialType.Windows;
binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential;
binding.Security.Transport.ProtectionLevel = System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.EncryptAndSign;
```

All is working well, until I add authorization using

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "Administrators")]
```

The client and service are both running with the same user which is the member of the local Administrators group. When I call the service from the client, I always get the following exception:

```
System.Security.SecurityException: Request for principal permission failed.
at System.Security.Permissions.PrincipalPermission.ThrowSecurityException()
at System.Security.Permissions.PrincipalPermission.Demand()
at System.Security.PermissionSet.DemandNonCAS()
.
.
.
The action that failed was:
Demand
The type of the first permission that failed was:
System.Security.Permissions.PrincipalPermission
The first permission that failed was:
<IPermission class="System.Security.Permissions.PrincipalPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
version="1">
<Identity Authenticated="true"
Role="Administrators"/>
</IPermission>

The demand was for:
<IPermission class="System.Security.Permissions.PrincipalPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
version="1">
<Identity Authenticated="true"
Role="Administrators"/>
</IPermission>
```

I get the same exception when I apply the PrincipalPermission attribute either to the class or its methods.
Also inside the methods

```
ServiceSecurityContext.Current;
```

is always null. I am doing something fundamentally wrong, but I can't figure what.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not necessarily due to the literal meaning of the error, but could also be caused by the missing `<authentication>` tag and associated settings in web.config.

You can take a look at [this docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/bb398990(v=vs.100)) to see the settings. I hope it helps.